# NullReferenceException even when after "new MyType[]"?

Tags: c#, arrays, nullreferenceexception

I am using MSChart and I am creating array like this

```
DataPoint[] datapoint = new DataPoint[10];
datapoint[0].SetValueY(86);
```

but it is giving error

> NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Why is it giving error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array initially contains 10 `null` references. You have to populate it with actual object references before using it. Try something like:

```
DataPoint[] datapoint = new DataPoint[10];
for (int i = 0; i < datapoint.Length; ++i) {
    datapoint[i] = new DataPoint();
}

datapoint[0].SetValueY(86);
```

Comment: `new` keyword is used to create memory, then in `DataPoint[] datapoint = new DataPoint[10]` what is doing `new` keyword?

Comment: @jams, it allocates enough memory to fit a new array object of the size you specify, initially containing null references. In short, the array object does exist, but not the items it contains.

Answer (score 3):

Because the object at index `0` in the `datapoint` array is null.

Add this line before the `SetValueY` method call:

```
datapoint[0] = new DataPoint();
```

You'll need to do this for each index in the array (0 - 9) or populate the array with DataPoint objects some other way (using LINQ, for example)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `DataPoint` but it appears that it is a `class`.  Hence the expression `new DataPoint[10]` creates an array of 10 values all of which are initialized to `null`.  You'll need to initialize the elements before using them.  For example

```
datapoint[0] = new DataPoint();
datapoint[0].SetValueY(86);
```

Comment: `new` keyword is used to create memory, then in `DataPoint[] datapoint = new DataPoint[10]` what is doing `new` keyword?

Comment: @jams you can view it as creating a 10 consecutive slots in which `DataPoint` values can be stored.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the DataPoints in the array.

```
DataPoint[] datapoint = new DataPoint[10];
datapoint[0] = new DataPoint();
datapoint[0].SetValueY(86);
```